# How to save compiled files in a separate directory using makefile?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a Fortran 90 code using the following Makefile in VS Code on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1. Now I want to have all types of files those generated during compilation (e.g., MODS XML or *.mod, Unix Executable or *.exe, *.o) in a separate folder named **Build**. Is there a simple way I can edit my Makefile so that I can get the expected result? I have tried changing `OBJDIR` with the help of some related answers provided in StackOverflow. This didn't give me any error, but it didn't give me what I want. All files generated during compilation are still in the main directory.

```
# Compiler settings - Can be customized.
CC = gfortran
CPP = gfortran -cpp
CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic
LDFLAGS =

# Makefile settings - Can be customized.
APPNAME = myapp
EXT = .f90
SRCDIR = src
#OBJDIR = obj
###### I make change here######
OBJDIR = ${SRCDIR}/Build

############## Do not change anything from here downwards! #############
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT))
#OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
###### I make change here######
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%$(EXT), $(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
DEP = $(OBJ:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=%.d)
# UNIX-based OS variables & settings
RM = rm
DELOBJ = $(OBJ)
# Windows OS variables & settings
DEL = del
EXE = .exe
#WDELOBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)\\%.o)
###### I make change here######
WDELOBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%$(EXT), $(OBJDIR)\\%.o,$(SOURCES))

########################################################################
####################### Targets beginning here #########################
########################################################################

all: $(APPNAME)

# Builds the app
$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Creates the dependecy rules
%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
@$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:%.d=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) >$@

# Includes all .h files
-include $(DEP)

# Building rule for .o files and its .c/.cpp in combination with all .h
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
$(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

################### Cleaning rules for Unix-based OS ###################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: clean
clean:
   $(RM) $(DELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandep
cleandep:
  $(RM) $(DEP)

#################### Cleaning rules for Windows OS #####################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: clean
clean:
   $(DEL) $(WDELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)$(EXE)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandepw
cleandepw:
 $(DEL) $(DEP)
```

Comment: Do you understand how this makefile works? Have you tried changing the value of `OBJDIR`?

Comment: I tried `OBJDIR  = ${SRCDIR}/Build`. But didn't work. And sorry, I don't understand clearly how this makefile works. That's why I messed it up while trying some solutions from here.

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem we can solve.  Please edit your question, show the change you made to the makefile, then explain what happened when you tried to run it (cutting and pasting errors etc. into your question).  In a very brief scan of your makefile it seems that changing `OBJDIR` should do what you want, so we need more information.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @MadScientist. I have edited the question with the changes I made.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what command you typed or what errors you got.  But your change is wrong, if you faithfully reproduced it here.  The old setting was `OBJDIR = obj` which set the variable `OBJDIR` to the value `obj`.  You replaced that assignment with just the string `${SRCDIR}/Build`, which is not a variable assignment; in fact it's just a syntax error.  You have to assign the variable, like `OBJDIR = ${SRCDIR}/Build`.

Comment: I didn't get any error messages. The problem is I didn't get the result I wanted.

I make 3 changes to the code. Above all 3 changes, I add `###### I make change here######`.

Comment: You need to change your compilation rules to put the objects (-o) into the Build directory.

Comment: I change the compilation rule to `-o0/Build,` but still it is producing compilation files in the `src` folder.

Comment: Most of your makefile is a complicated black box whose inner working you don't understand, and which we can't easily replicate. (I for one have an aversion to Fortran.) This makes it almost impossible to solve this puzzle.

Comment: @Beta I don't I will be alone to have an aversion to people who have to voice their aversion to Fortran in the fortran tag questions.